# Prove that if $v$ and $w$ are linearly independent in $\mathbb{R}^3$, then $\{ v, w, v \times w\}$ is also linearly independent

Tags: linear-algebra

Please help, I don't know how to go with this. So far I've done this :

if $c_1v + c_2w + c_3(v\times w) = 0$ , then $c_1,c_2,c_3$ must be $0$, and $0$ must be the only solution.

Answer (score 1):

I would use the fact that
$0 
= v\cdot (v\times w)
= w\cdot (v\times w)
$.

If
$v\times w
= av+bw$
then
$0
=v\cdot(v\times w)
= v\cdot(av+bw)
=a|v|^2+b(v\cdot w)
$
and
$0
=w\cdot(v\times w)
= w\cdot(av+bw)
=av\cdot w+b|w|^2
$
which implies
$a = b = 0$.

Comment: $\times$ is `\times`

Comment: Thanks for reducing my ignorance.

Answer (score 0):

By (one) definition, $a \times b$ is the unique vector satisfying
$\langle x, a \times b \rangle = \det \begin{bmatrix} x & a & b \end{bmatrix} $, and in particular we have $\|a \times b \|^2 = \det \begin{bmatrix} a \times b & a & b \end{bmatrix}$.

Hence we see that $a \times b = 0$ **iff** $a,b$ are
linearly dependent.

To see this note that if $a,b$ are linearly dependent, then 
$\|a \times b \|^2 = \det \begin{bmatrix} a \times b & a & b \end{bmatrix} =0$ and so $a \times b = 0$. On the other hand, if $a \times b = 0$, then $\det \begin{bmatrix} x & a & b \end{bmatrix} = 0$
for all vectors $x$ and so we must have that $a,b$ are linearly
dependent (otherwise we could find a basis for $\mathbb{R}^3$ of the
form $a,b,x$ for which $\det \begin{bmatrix} x & a & b \end{bmatrix} \neq 0$, a contradiction).

Hence we have
$a,b$ are linearly independent **iff** $a \times b \neq 0$ **iff**
$\det \begin{bmatrix} a \times b & a & b \end{bmatrix} \neq 0$ **iff** 
$a,b,a \times b$ are linearly independent.